# mysql transform row to column with condition

Tags: mysql

is it possible to convert mysql rows to columns in this manner?

suppose i have a table like this

```
+-----+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
| id  | std_no       | exam_id | subject_code | score |
+-----+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
|   1 | 1000         |       1 |          101 |    70 |
|   2 | 1000         |       1 |          102 |    75 |
|   3 | 1000         |       1 |          121 |    75 |
|   4 | 1000         |       1 |          231 |    69 |
|   7 | 1001         |       1 |          101 |    80 |
|   8 | 1001         |       1 |          102 |    70 |
|   9 | 1001         |       1 |          121 |    90 |
|  10 | 1001         |       1 |          231 |    80 |
| 127 | 1000         |       2 |          101 |    61 |
| 128 | 1000         |       2 |          102 |    85 |
| 129 | 1000         |       2 |          121 |    50 |
| 130 | 1000         |       2 |          231 |    54 |
| 133 | 1001         |       2 |          101 |    63 |
| 134 | 1001         |       2 |          102 |    14 |
| 135 | 1001         |       2 |          121 |    90 |
| 136 | 1001         |       2 |          231 |    25 |
+-----+--------------+---------+--------------+-------+
```

and i need to create a new table based on the above like this:

```
+-----+----------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| id  | std_no         |subject_code | exam1 | exam2 |         
+-----+----------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| 1   | 1000           | 101         | 70    | 61    |
| 2   | 1000           | 102         | 75    | 85    |
| 3   | 1000           | 121         | 75    | 50    |
| 4   | 1000           | 231         | 69    | 54    |
| 5   | 1001           | 101         | 80    | 63    |
| 6   | 1001           | 102         | 70    | 14    |
| 7   | 1001           | 121         | 90    | 90    |
| 8   | 1001           | 231         | 80    | 25    |
+-----+----------------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

as in go through the first table,get the **std_no**,**subject_code**,and **score**.however i need to put the scor**e inside table2 under exam1 if table1.exam_id=1 and in table2 under exam2 if table1.exam_id=2**

is this possible with mysql ?

Comment: Do you actually want to create a new table with those columns, or rather just produce results that are laid out with the exams listed as columns?  Are the number exams fixed (are there only 2 exams) or is it dynamic?

Comment: Is there only two `exam_id` i.e. `1 and 2` ?

Comment: @Martin Parkin.  there will be more exam columns so it is dynamic

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty  they are four exam_id. i just put two to reduce on typing

Comment: @GOA You will need to use a pivot table to achieve this.  Check out this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table for some help.

Comment: @MartinParkin .i will produce a new table and thanks for the pivot table pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamic `exam_id` you need to create a dynamic query for generating the pivot table something as

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when exam_id = ''',
      exam_id,
      ''' then score end) AS ',
      concat('exam',exam_id)
    )
  ) into @sql
from exam;

set @sql = concat('select std_no,subject_code, ', @sql, ' from exam 
                  group by std_no,subject_code
                  order by std_no,subject_code
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

In the expected result set you also have some `id` incremental order and to get that you can alter the above query to use user defined variable for the same as

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when exam_id = ''',
      exam_id,
      ''' then score end) AS ',
      concat('exam',exam_id)
    )
  ) into @sql
from exam;

set @sql = concat('select @rn:=@rn+1 as id,std_no,subject_code, ', @sql, ' from exam,(select @rn:=0)x
                  group by std_no,subject_code
                  order by std_no,subject_code
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bced/8)**

Comment: tested your code in fiddle and it seems to work like i need.i just first have to wrap my head around the new concepts of sql variables and prepared statements then try it on the live database

Answer (score 0):

These query gives you records somewhat similar to your output with null values

```
SELECT id,std_no,subject_code,
  (CASE exam_id WHEN 1 THEN score ELSE NULL END) as exam1,
  (CASE exam_id WHEN 2 THEN score ELSE NULL END) as exam2
FROM table;
```

Comment: I think the OP is not looking for `some what` result.

Comment: yes sure but it gives Null values thatswhy i am just used this word here

Comment: Your result does not cater for anything other than exams 1 or 2.  The op wishes to dynamically display the exam results in a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a self join

```
SELECT a.id,a.std_no,a.subject_code,
  a.score as exam1,b.score as exam2
FROM table a join table b
  on a.std_no=b.std_no and 
  a.subject_code=b.subject_code 
  WHERE a.exam_id=1 and b.exam_id=2;
```

Comment: Your result only shows for exams 1 and 2 - this would not allow for the display of exams 3, 4, etc. dynamically as requested.

Comment: @MartinParkin yeah. Noticed the comments just now

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id, std_no, subject_code,
       MAX(CASE WHEN exam_id = 1 THEN score END) as exam1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN exam_id = 2 THEN score END) as exam2
FROM table
GROUP BY std_no, subject_code;
```